# Prove there $\operatorname{lcm}[a_{k},a_{k+1}]>ck$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$ distinct postive integers .$0<c<\dfrac{3}{2}$

Show that:

there exsit infinitely postive integer $k$ such
$$\operatorname{lcm}[a_{k},a_{k+1}]>ck$$

From:[2015 china TsT](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1062614_china_team_selection_test_2015_tst_1_day_1_q2):

Comment: Did you mean LCM? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I want use induction

Comment: You can't use induction if it is false infinitely often. For example, if, infinitely often, $a_{k}$ divides $a_{k+1}$ and $a_{k+1} \le k+1$, this is false for these $k$ for any $c \ge 1+1/k$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem background and solution can see

[Baidu tieba](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/3635493103)

The key is
$$\dfrac{1}{[a_{i},a_{i+1}]}\le\dfrac{1}{3}\left(\dfrac{1}{a_{i}}+\dfrac{1}{a_{i+1}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial solution,
which shows that
is it true for
$c = 1$.

Want to show that
$lcm[a_{k},a_{k+1}]>ck
$
infinitely often.

Since the $a_k$
are distinct,
$max(a_k)_{k=1}^n
\ge n
$.

Let $a_n$ be such that
$a_n = max(a_k)_{k=1}^n
$.
There are an infinite number of these,
since the $a_n$
are distinct positive integers.
For these $a_n$,
$a_n \ge n$.

Since
$lcm(a, b)
\ge max(a, b)
$,
$lcm(a_{n-1}, a_n)
\ge max(a_{n-1}, a_n)
\ge a_n
\ge n
$.

Right now,
I don't see how to
push $c > 1$.
If we could choose
an $a_{n-1}$ which does not
divide one of these extreme $a_n$
 infinitely often,
it looks like we count
get an unbounded $c$,
maybe.

Comment: Good idea,maybe find recurrence relation?

Comment: As I said in a comment above, that relation can be false infinitely often (for example, if $a_k | a_{k+1}$ and $a_{k+1}$ is small).

Comment: You can see this problem:http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h407542p2276540

Comment: I thought of $gcd(a, b)lcm(a,b) = ab$, but wasn't able to use it.